# Is there a Japanese equivalent to "I guess I could do X"?

Tags: grammar

I was wondering if there was an equivalent to say "I guess" in the way you might use it if someone were to ask you to do something, or suggest doing something, such as being asked to take out the trash, and you reply with "I guess I could take it out". I guess I'm looking for a similar way to say that in a way where you don't really want to do it, but you'll do it anyways.

Would something like this be close (also, please correct my terrible grammar):

> お母さん:　ゴミを出してください。
> 少年:　後でゴミを出すけど、出したくないです。

Or is there a different way to express a similar meaning to "I guess I could put out the trash (even though I'd rather not do it)"?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use something like 「このゴミ、捨てよっか」 *Guess I'll throw this trash out.* Not exactly "I'd rather not do it" but "There's nothing better so I guess I'll do that". This isn't a very formal saying either.

You could also say 「このゴミを捨てなきゃ」or more politely 「このゴミを捨てなければ。。。」which is more about "I'd rather not" but need to or have too.

Comment: The intonation would be very important too.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say 仕方ないなー.
It literally means "There's no way to do it". So like, "I guess I have no choice/no other way around this."